# What is a better way to setup mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a set of documents that are the same but could be sorted into two distinct groups based on usage.

One of these groups, we'll call them "current", has a low volume of documents being queried a lot.

The other group, we'll call them "backlog", is a huge volume of documents queried much less often.

My thought was that not mixing these these two types of the same document would allow me to query the very active "current" docs without needing to sift through the huge amount of "backlog" every time.

Should these be in two different collections or the same "cars" collection?

```
mongo.collection('cars', function(err, cars){
    cars.find({type:'new', color:'blue'}).toArray(function(err, newBlueCars) {
        //do something with newBlueCars
    });
});

mongo.collection('cars', function(err, cars){
    cars.find({type:'used', color:'blue'}).toArray(function(err, usedBlueCars) {
        //do something with usedBlueCars
    });
});
```

OR

```
mongo.collection('cars.current', function(err, cars){
    cars.find({color:'blue'}).toArray(function(err, currentBlueCars) {
        //do something with newBlueCars
    });
});

mongo.collection('cars.backlog', function(err, cars){
    cars.find({color:'blue'}).toArray(function(err, backlogBlueCars) {
        //do something with usedBlueCars
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you ever want to query them together? That's a strong argument for keeping them in the same collection. If not, two collections probably makes sense.

Comment: @WesFreeman Could I use collection name spacing for the rare events that I do? cars.current, cars.backlog

Comment: @fancy: Yes, but it would be two queries instead of one I believe

Comment: @dji I think if you namespace you can just query the "cars" collection but the actual process is still equivalent to two different collection queries. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @fancy They would be two separate collections (jdi is right, separate queries). Example: https://gist.github.com/2431396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I would post an actual answer, now that it has been sufficiently hashed out in comments (the other answer isn't quite good enough).

The benefits of keeping it all in one collection are:

- Can query all records in a single query
- Can use sparse index to efficiently index the "current" records

The downsides of keeping it all in one collection are:

- Indexes probably need to have the "current" field leading all of them, which takes extra space and makes lookups slower
- Can't index multiple fields with a sparse index

The benefits of splitting them into two collections are:

- You get a free index, so you don't need to lead all of your indexes with the "current" field
- Your "current" data will have much smaller indexes that can easily fit in RAM

The downsides of splitting them into two collections are:

- You'll need to run two queries to do anything with the dataset as a whole, and merge the results

Answer (score 1):

You can index type & color together and get a nice response time, there is no need to seperate them in two collections, it is not a good practice for maintainability. You may need same operations on both, but in this way, you will need to repeat everything twice.

Comment: I would add that new and used cars share almost the exact same set of properties. "type" is just another property with two possible values. It would make as much sense to separate them on that property as it would to start creating new collections for different color cars. The ability to index on multiple levels of a document keeps this search fast regardless.

Comment: @jdi well there is more going into this then the cars example. Maybe it should be "in production" cars and then a back catalog of every car ever made. one set of data is going to be smaller and queried all the time where as the back catalog is going to be huge and rarely queried. I'm thinking if the "in production" cars are going to be used all the time you could create a faster query by keeping them separate from the huge backlog

Comment: @fancy: That is something that sharding on a key can do for you when performance becomes an actual concern. You wouldn't have to logically separate the "cars". Just shard them on the "production" property at some point. If I am wrong about sharding being the answer here, there are also other solutions such as sparse indexes which would only ever consider "production" cars in a query since they have the sparse index.

Comment: @jdi Your first comment about type being another property is true, however, if you never need to query them together, splitting them into two collections, your index becomes less complex and your response time on the hot data will be faster. On the other hand, if they really are the same schema, then it will be easier to migrate records to archive status just by setting the status value, if they're in the same collection.

Comment: @WesFreeman: But you could make a sparse index called "isProduction", and then the index would **only** contain those docs which have that index. Wouldn't that make it fast while keeping everything in one collection? It shouldn't matter how many docs are in the collection but rather how you index those docs.

Comment: This was an answer from someone at 10gen on the mailing list... Spencer:
It would make sense to split those out so that you'll be able to keep the 
entire index of the smaller collection in memory, without having to use any 
memory to store index entries that correspond to the less-frequently 
queried documents.

Comment: @jdi would a sparse index do the same thing?

Comment: @fancy: Probably not the same completely. I'm no mongo expert, but I think the the sparse index alone would be smaller, yet any other indexes would contribute to the memory usage. So, then maybe you should just split them :-)

Comment: @jdi I pinged him back asking about using the sparse index approach. Seems like it would also work quite well. I will post his response here. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: And thank you Mustafa for letting us dominate your answer thread!

Comment: Keep in mind that a sparse index requires that a field not exist, so you'd have something like production:1 for your production records, and nothing for production for your archive records, and then do db.cars.ensureIndex({production:1},{sparse:true}). I think it still is a question of whether you'd ever want to query them together--if so, put them in the same collection with a sparse index. If not, keep them split.

Comment: It's possible that I would query them together but I can't see the need to do it very often, so i don't think the double query will kill me, especially in async node.js. I think it might be a lot simpler and cleaner to let them  exist in different collections so I will likely chose that approach for now. Thanks again.

Comment: @jdi folow up on sparse index from 10gen guy: You could have a field to indicate if it's current or not.  If you use a 
sparse index on it, you'll only be able to look up documents that have the 
field, not the ones that don't, so it only helps you filter to either the 
"current" or the "backlog" documents, not both....

Comment: Also, that index wouldn't 
help you for any queries where you try to match on any other fields - the 
only way to do that is to prefix the 'isCurrent' field to every normal 
index you want to use for querying. 

The easiest thing is probably to separate them into 2 collection and then 
if you need to query both just do 2 queries and combine the results 
client-side, but the strategy of prefixing the 'isCurrent' field to every 
index could work also if you can't do that for some reason.

Comment: That's true, and definitely another thing to keep in mind. How many "current" items might there be? If it's < ~10k, doing a sparse index scan is probably fine. Sparse indexes can only have one field as it is now. Expanding that functionality is still in a planning category for mongodb: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-785